# MongoDB - Filter and update multi nested data

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to delete one nested document.

```py
mycol = mongodb["structure"]

mycol.update_one(
    { "name" : "New Folder" },
    {"$pull" : {"structure.$.values" : {"report_name": "Area test"}}}
)
```

MongoDB data:

```
[{
    "structure":  [
        {
            "name": "New Folder",
            "values": [
            {
                "report_name": "Area test",
                "report_heading": "Area test",
            },
            {
                "report_name": "multi same",
                "report_heading": "multi same",
            },
            
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I am using the above code to delete one document from the nested object. But my above query not working. Please take a look.

Expected result:

```
[{
    "structure":  [
        {
            "name": "New Folder",
            "values": [
            {
                "report_name": "multi same",
                "report_heading": "multi same",
            },
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document consists of `structure` array. To do updating the multi-nested document, you need [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) filtered positional operator.

```
db.collection.update({
  "structure.name": "New Folder"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "structure.$[structure].values": {
      "report_name": "Area test"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "structure.name": "New Folder"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zm_fz6jmjT6)

Comment: I am using pymongo. How i will get arrayFilters ?

Comment: Nevermind fixed the issue able to convert into pymongo

Comment: No problem. Slightly late but glad to see you get the answer. With `array_filters=[...]`. Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-mongodb-update_one/